# TestCafe and Gitlab started failing with

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, testcafe

When I am running Testcafe in our GitLab environment, we started seeing this issue once updating our node:

`Firefox 106.0 / Linux 0.0`

`went from 1.22.9-gke.2000 to 1.23.14-gke.1800`

```
GeneralError: The Chrome 110.0.5481.177 / Linux 0.0 browser disconnected. If you did not close the browser yourself, browser performance or network issues may be at fault.
    at BrowserConnection._createBrowserDisconnectedError (/builds/engineering/qa/ui-acceptance-tests/node_modules/.pnpm/testcafe@2.4.0/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/connection/index.ts:320:16)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/builds/engineering/qa/ui-acceptance-tests/node_modules/.pnpm/testcafe@2.4.0/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/connection/index.ts:325:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  code: 'E1002',
  data: [ 'Chrome 110.0.5481.177 / Linux 0.0' ]
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your gitlab-ci yaml and runner configuration to your question by [edit]ing it in. Also add the transcript of the screenshot. And have you reported the problem upstream? Have you searched if the problem existed in the past with that project? ([it did](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6942))